# Why is my regex not working to remove a section of a fasta header

Tags: unix, fasta

I want to remove everything between the ">" and "Un_" in a heading such as

```
>NW_017859640.1 Esox lucius isolate CL-BC-CA-002 unplaced genomic scaffold, Eluc_V3 Un_scaffold1210
```

I've tried multiple iterations of regexes. Nothing that contains "*" seems to work

```
sed 's/^NC_*Eluc_V3 //'
```

and using this pattern

```
sed 's/NC_*Eluc_V3 //'
```

What I would like in the end is

```
>Un_scaffold1210
```

Comment: The greedy match is to use `.*` and not just `*`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with:

```
sed 's/^>.*Un_/>Un_/'
```

Here I'm searching for `>` at the beginning of the line, followed by things and ending with `Un_`, and substituting this string by just `>Un_`.

Seems easier to look for what you told us that are your markers than trying to guess what should be inside those markers, as you are trying to do.